# In .NET, what's the difference between AsFoo() and ToFoo()?

Tags: .net, naming-conventions

For example, `enumerable.ToList()` versus `list.AsReadOnly()`.

I ask because I've got a class that turns an `IEnumerable<T>` into an `IDataReader`. I wonder whether the extension method that creates it should be `ToDataReader` or `AsDataReader`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`As*` methods return a different interface without iterating the source, while `To*` iterates over it and creates a new object.

In your case, `AsDataReader` should be the right choice, as you don't iterate over the source when creating the `DataReader`, but only when the user calls methods on it.